# setup two way binding into url using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to todo **two way** binding into url.In the following code I'm setting it but, when the url is changing new and old value showing up the same that get on first page load. Please suggest how can set up `$rootScope.xyz_form = false;` when page having `xyz_form` value into `url`

```
$rootScope.siteUrl = $location.path();
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
 $rootScope.$watch('siteUrl', function (newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log("newVal", newVal);
      console.log("oldVal", oldVal);

      if (newVal.indexOf('xyz_form') > 0) {
        $rootScope.xyz_form = false;
        }else{
            $rootScope.xyz_form = true;
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `$rootScope`

When the page is reloading `$rootScope` is also reinitializing. At the same time your `Controller` also re-initializing. So it can't `watch` the change in `$rootScope`.

So one possible solution is to use **local storage or Session storage**.
There is `$localStorage` and `$sessionStorage` dependencies for AngulrJs.

The content's in **local storage will remain for ever until me delete them**

By installing `ngStorage` you can use both `$localStorage` and `sessionStorage`

For more info [Read here](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

Comment: @JAckJakhmola Can you please explain "$localStorage does not work for me" ?

Comment: var siteUrl = $location.path();
if (siteUrl.indexOf('xyz_form') > 0) {
        $localStorage.xyz_page = false;
        }else{
            $localStorage.xyz_page = true;
        }

Comment: even through i  delete $localStorage.xyz_page but it shows me true values always

Comment: Please do create a jsFiddle for your problem. I can give you the solution then.